# Ntfsfix "Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk." even after chkdsk

Tags: fedora, permissions, filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-3g

Recently on my NTFS drive I encountered that I can't do any write: remove or create things. I ran `ntfsfix /dev/sda3`.

#### Not mounted

```bash
Mounting volume... Error opening read-only '/dev/sda3': Permission denied
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening read-only '/dev/sda3': Permission denied
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Permission denied
Error opening '/dev/sda3': Read-only file system
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

#### Mounted

```bash
Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda3.
# But i still can't write on it.
```

But even after I run `chkdsk` on Windows, the same error is there, and I still can't write to it.

### Specs

```bash
OS: Fedora Linux 38 (KDE Plasma) x86_64 
Host: MS-7D18 2.0 
Kernel: 6.3.12-200.fc38.x86_64 
Uptime: 10 mins 
Packages: 1976 (rpm), 12 (flatpak) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 5.27.6 
WM: kwin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: tmux 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11400 (12) @ 4.400GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate 
Memory: 2522MiB / 15875MiB
```